# How to add shapefile name as attribute during merge?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, open-source-gis, attribute-table, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add field with filename when merging shapefiles with ogr2ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22175/how-to-add-field-with-filename-when-merging-shapefiles-with-ogr2ogr)

I have more 200 shapefiles with a unique name. I would like to merge all of these together and save the name of each individual shapefile as an attribute for each feature in the merged shapefile. Does anyone know if this is possible using the Open GIS (no proprietary GIS), plugins for Open GIS? Thanks!