# Importing multiple shapefiles into single PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I have a folder full of shapefiles that I want to import into a single PostGIS table. This table should have the following columns:

```
id, filename, multipolygon
```

I can bulk import all shapefiles using the SPIT plugin for QGIS, but each shapefile has different attributes, thus they are placed in different tables and I cannot append them into just one. I don't really want any of the attributes, I just want each polygon to be associated with the file from which it came.

I've tried two basic strategies, and neither looks very promising to me:

- Import all files normally and use SQL queries to extract the information I want from each table. My SQLfu is not strong enough to do this yet. In particular, how do I get the name of the file associated with the corresponding rows?
- Programmatically generate .dbf files with the associated filename as an attribute. Then import all files normally and append to a single table. Seems quite hacky.

I realize very similar questions have been posted before, but none of them seem to address this issue. I am just starting with GIS tools

Comment: Try merge shapefiles in QGIS: Vector - Data Management Tools - Merge shapefiles to one, then import this shapefile in PostGIS.

Comment: @HasT Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to do that and I can successfully get all of the polygons into a single table, but it's not clear how I can compute the association between polygon <--> filename.

Comment: Try QGIS plugin for merging shapefiles Merge shapes, - there is option add file name to column (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22175/how-to-add-field-with-filename-when-merging-shapefiles-with-ogr2ogr)

Comment: Does this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7803/bulk-load-multiple-shapefiles-into-postgis?rq=1 help?

Comment: I haven't had time to comment for a few days. @HasT, I was using the plugin that came with QGIS, which does not have the option to add file name to column. I found the one you refer to, and it does what I needed, so thanks! martin f I looked through that thread and saw a couple of things that were promising, but it didn't contain all the info I needed. Thanks though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem could be this:

1) Create a new schema in your PostgreSQL. Let's call it `temp`.

2) Let SPIT plugin for QGIS do its job, but import all the shapefiles in the `temp` schema.

3) Run this script:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
    cTable CURSOR FOR SELECT demo.table_name FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'temp') as demo;
    tStatement text;
    nFlag integer;
BEGIN
    tStatement := '';
    nFlag := 0;
    FOR table_record IN cTable LOOP
        -- for every table in the temp schema add a new column
        -- having the table name inserted in each table row
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE temp.' || table_record.table_name || 
        E' ADD COLUMN source_file character varying(64) DEFAULT \'' 
        || table_record.table_name || E'\'::character varying';

        -- build the UNION statement for all the tables
    IF nFlag > 0 THEN
        tStatement := 'SELECT geom, source_file FROM temp.' || table_record.table_name || ' UNION ALL ' || tStatement;      
    ELSE
        nFlag := 1;
        tStatement := 'SELECT geom, source_file FROM temp.' || table_record.table_name; 
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    -- create a new table (in an other schema) based on UNION result
    tStatement := 'CREATE TABLE public.demo_union WITH OIDS AS ' || tStatement; 
    -- RAISE NOTICE 'sql statement: %', tStatement;
    EXECUTE tStatement;
END$$;
```

This way you will obtain a `demo_union` table inside your `public` schema, after that you can drop the `temp` schema:

[image]