# Merge uniquely named point shapefiles in 50,000 different folders into a single layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge

I have point shapefiles in 50,000 different folders (each shapefile file name is unique) - about 33,400 shapefiles (not all folders will have a point shapefile). I like to open the point shapefile in each of the folder into QGIS Desktop 2.2.0 map frame and then hopefully run a merge on them to get a single point shapefile layer. I tried drag-dropping from Windows Explorer to QGIS, and QGIS froze initially and continue to add the point shapefiles for several hours and didn't seem to stop. I found the Load Them All plugin (http://goo.gl/HbJhhS) that seem to specify the feature type and also specify a string filter, this plugin also didn't seem to work...

I was thinking that had I planned well, I could've automated and copied the point shapefiles into another single folder as soon as they were created and I could 've dragged-dropped into mapframe from this single folder. I don't know if this would've had worked. My analysis run took 18 days to run, so I don't want to re-run just to do that. I tried copy-pasting with Windows Explorer and it hung, may be because it was 100,000+ files...

Would you know any trick to do this?

Comment: I recommend you use, though cannot direct how, Python!!!

Comment: Do the shape files, that are points, have a unique name? Like _pt.shp for example that distinguishes them from other shape files that aren't points?

Comment: Shapefiles are named: Poly1_Image1.shp, Poly2_Image1.shp, Poly3_Image1.shp, Poly4_Image4.shp, Poly5_Image5.shp.

Comment: @ArunGovind What problem did you have with Load Them All? The plugin was actually built for this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 9):

I advise merging your shapefiles into a single folder (using a program or search/copy/paste or a small script such as the one [Mark C recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089371/dos-batch-file-to-copy-certain-file-types-from-subdirectories-to-one-folder-with) in the comments). Then use this rather elegant bit of code from [gis-programming.com](http://gis-programming.com/?p=194):

> as above, use: ogr2ogr merge.shp file1.shp to create a shapefile merge
>   containing the data of file1
>
> then:

```
 for %f in (*.shp) do ( 

 ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp %f  -f “esri
 shapefile” -nln merge 

 )
```

Comment: That is really very elegant!

Comment: It would be nice to bring the shapes into a single folder, but if he uses a GUI, there could be a problem when the files exceed 65536 or something like that. There are ~50,000 shape files to deal with in this case. It would be easier to recursively search each folder and test for its geometry type instead.

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089371/dos-batch-file-to-copy-certain-file-types-from-subdirectories-to-one-folder-with) for a Dos Batch File to copy all the files into one common directory

Comment: This is a good answer, @ArunGovind. And if it's germane, I additionally recommend [reviewing the answers in this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22175/how-to-add-field-with-filename-when-merging-shapefiles-with-ogr2ogr/42782#42782) if it's worthwhile to add a new field to preserve/distinguish which points originally belonged to each of your merged shapefiles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution for those facing a similar problem in `R`:

```
library(sf)
library(magrittr)

# find all shape files
  all_shape_addresses <- list.files(path="R:/root_folder", pattern = ".shp", full.names =T, recursive = TRUE)

# read all files into a list
  files_list <- lapply(all_shape_addresses, st_read)

# Merge all files into a single object
  single <- Reduce(st_union, x)

# save single shape file
  st_write(single , dsn = "single.shp", layer = "single.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

I'm not sure how the speed would compare to the solutions presented in the other answers. The performance of the solution in R might be restricted due to memory constraints in case there are too many and too large shape files.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work. But thank you to everyone who answered and their awesome ideas! I'll explore each of them.

I used Global Mapper which has the option to search directories and its sub-directories for selected file types (File > Open all files in a directory tree). It took around 12 hours to load the shapefiles from 50,000 sub-folders and then I selected point or polygon layer and separately exported them as a new vector layer. The export took 15-30 minutes for each layer.

[image: All points and polygons]

[image: Selected points and polygons zoomed in]