# OSGeo4W / ogr2ogr gives "Unable to create or change a table without a primary key" error with MySQL 8.0

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, mysql, osgeo4w, mysql-spatial

I'm trying to use OSGeo4W Shell to populate my MySQL DB with data from a shapefile and am having some difficulty. Here's the command I'm using:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:maps,host=localhost,user=root,password=password tl_2020_us_county.shp -nln county_shapes -update -overwrite -lco engine=InnoDB -skipfailures
```

When I run that command I get this error:

> ERROR 1: MySQL error message:Unable to create or change a table without a primary key, when the system variable 'sql_require_primary_key' is set. Add a primary key to the table or unset this variable to avoid this message. Note that tables without a primary key can cause performance problems in row-based replication, so please consult your DBA before changing this setting. Description: CREATE TABLE `county_shapes` (    OGR_FID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    SHAPE GEOMETRY NOT NULL /*!80003 SRID 4269 */) ENGINE = InnoDB

If ogr2ogr were creating a MySQL dumpfile instead of trying to write to an SQL DB I could then either:

1. do `cat prepend.sql dump.sql | mysql ...` where prepend.sql contained `SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key = 0;`
2. modify the CREATE TABLE in the dumpfile to include a PRIMARY KEY.

But alas if there's a way to create dumpfile's using ogr2ogr that'd be news to me.

I also can't modify my mysqld-auto.cnf to add this in there as this is a managed database (like RDS on AWS).

If I could *append* to an existant table I could import it locally on a server where I can disable sql_require_primary_key in the mysqld-auto.cnf, get the schema from that import and then create that schema on the target server, either modifying it outright or by doing `SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key = 0;` before the `CREATE TABLE` but alas I can't even get that working as discussed at [ogr2ogr can't append shapefile to existing Postgres table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/342453/17847#comment702981_343077) (altho I do note that that answer is using PostgreSQL vs MySQL).

I also thought that if I import it to a local DB I could create a dumpfile from that server and import it to the prod one but [binary data is interfering with that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72214131/569976)

Comment: Add a primary key to your table?

Comment: @IanTurton - it's the CREATE TABLE query that's failing and I'm not the one creating the CREATE TABLE query - ogr2ogr is. If your proposal is that I modify the source code to ogr2ogr then that's a pretty extreme solution. Maybe, while I'm at it, I ought to make my own tool to convert a shapefile into a MySQL dumpfile!

Comment: Try removing the -update?

Comment: @IanTurton - didn't help :( I added more detail to my orig question if that helps