# Creating Virtual Layer as union of multiple layers with same schema in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, union, virtual-layer

I have a Layer Group `surveyor` with lots of layers (shapefiles) with seemingly random names, and with identical schemas. I would like to combine them all to one layer; preferably with a Virtual Layer. The following does work.

```sql
SELECT * FROM monday
UNION 
SELECT * FROM wed_22
UNION 
SELECT * FROM parking
```

However, this requires manually typing all the layers. Is there a better solution, where I won't have to manually type the layers?

Comment: You may want to have a look at merging those shapefiles - [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306074/93656) with the filename as column, using `ogr2ogr` (with this you could also merge into a different file format, or into a GPKG/DB directly)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use python to print out the sql needed in the console, then copy paste it to the virtual layer. Add all layers to a group named surveyor and execute:

```py
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layerlist = []

#List the layers in surveyor group
for layergroup in root.children():
    if layergroup.name() == 'surveyor':
        for lyr in layergroup.children():
            layerlist.append(lyr.layer().name())

#Print the sql
for n, layer in enumerate(layerlist):
    print("select * from {}".format(layer))
    if n<len(layerlist)-1: #Dont print "union" at the end
        print("union")
```

[image]

Comment: To work only with shapefiles, please refer to this thread : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430438/getting-all-shapefile-layers-in-project-using-pyqgis

Comment: I expect OP to understand to only place the vector layers in sruveyor layer group

Answer (score 4):

Another possible workflow.

**Step 1.** Apply the ["Merge vector layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) tool from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

**Step 2.** Create a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` with the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "Merged"
```

Comment: The main purpose of virtual layers is to avoid writing redundant data on the disk....