# Merge multiple tables (100 tables) into a new table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am looking to merge a large number of individual tables into a new table in PostGIS. I have almost 100 "identical" tables so I wanted to do it automatically. There is a good answer here [Merge Multiple Tables into a New Table in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27402/merge-multiple-tables-into-a-new-table-in-postgis) but it is just for a few tables.

Comment: Do you have QGIS? You can use this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430972/virtual-layer-that-shows-the-union-of-multiple-layers-with-same-schema/430986#430986 to print out the SQL needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL solution using a simple `DO` block.

This assumes you have a `<target_schema>.<target_table>` in place to receive the `INSERT`ed data; I would prefer this over e.g. a collective `CREATE TABLE` statement (which is *faster*) to explicitly define column types (and *typemods*) and keys/constraints:

```
DO
$DO$
  DECLARE
    _shm TEXT;
    _tbl TEXT;
    
  BEGIN
    FOR _shm, _tbl IN (
      SELECT
        pt.schemaname,
        pt.tablename
      FROM
        pg_tables AS pt
      WHERE
        pt.schemaname = '<source_schema>'
        AND
        pt.tablename LIKE '<source_tables_common_name_pattern>'
    ) LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Merging table: %.%...', _shm, _tbl;

      EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $FORMAT$
          INSERT INTO <target_schema>.<target_table>(<optional_column_list>) (
            SELECT * FROM %1$I.%2$I
          );

          -- DROP TABLE %1$I.%2$I CASCADE;
        $FORMAT$,
        _shm, _tbl
      );
    END LOOP;
  END;
$DO$
;
```

**Notes:**

- **run the *outer* `LOOP` query individually prior to executing the `DO` block** to verfiy the correct tables are selected
- `<source_tables_common_name_pattern>` needs to be used in conjunction with the `%` wildcard to make sense
- `<optional_column_list>` should be used e.g. if you have an auto-incremental `PRIMARY KEY` identifier in the `<target_schema>.<target_table>` - you may want to also specify the exact columns in the `SELECT` list inside the `INSERT` statement, rather than using `*`
- run `VACUUM ANALYZE <target_schema>.<target_table>` when done
- OPTIONALLY: uncomment the `DROP TABLE` statement if you want to also delete the current source table in one go - otherwise you can run this same `DO` block with only the `DROP TABLE` statement afterwards

Comment: @geozlot it works thanks. BTW, I did some slight modifications. "pt.schema_name" should be "pt.schemaname" and "pt.table_name" to "pt.tablename". Also if your schema is not the public schema you should change the search path like: 'SET search_path TO your_schema, public;'

Comment: @FardinEsmaeili I added the schema qualification to the statement. No need to set the search_path.